# INTO keyword in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm not familiar with MS Access and need to convert some queries to work with MySQL. One includes the INTO keyword, which I don't believe exists in MySQL.

This doesn't seem to Google well, and I can't find a definition for it. Can anyone describe what it does, or point me to a description?

The actual query looks like this:

```
SELECT capdata.FldMake INTO Makes FROM capdata GROUP BY capdata.FldMake;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the answer - had already checked W3schools but managed to miss this. D'oh!

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: @MardinYadegar I'm well aware of that, but in this case they were all I could find that had anything on the subject.

Comment: I know, I just don't want people who think they're awesome to come on and make fun of you for it haha.